# Use the start() function for the discord python extention instead of run()

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So I've been looking everywhere, but the only way people seemed to run the bots is by using .run(TOKEN). But I'd like to use .start() instead, but don't know how to implement it in the code. Here something very simple it should be able to run:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

client.start(TOKEN)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")
```

Whenever I run this code I just get 2 Unclosed client sessions right before it closes the program

Comment: `start` is a coroutine, so you'll need to manually manage the event loop. [The docs for `run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run) have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will be using `client.start` instead of `client.run`, you will have to put it in an event loop. Below is example code.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(client.start('TOKEN'))
```